# how to do set union operations on arrays?

Tags: distinct, flatten, singlestore

Here's what I want to accomplish -

1. I want to have an `array[string]` column in a singlestore columnar table
2. Do a set union operation on this column over some time range/conditions.

I don't know how to express this in Singlestore sql.
Singlestore doesn't support array columns, so I've resorted to using json col.
Any pointers ?

Sample table

```
| key   | locations                         |
| ----- | --------------------------------- |
| alice | ["sanjose", "sancarlos", "miami"] |
| alice | ["sanjose","milpitas"]            |
| alice | ["miami"]                         |
| alice | ["sanmateo","sanfrancisco"]       |
| alice | ["redwoodshores","sanfrancisco"]  |
| bob   | ["sanjose","milpitas"]            |
| bob   | ["freemont","onioncity"]          |
| bob   | ["onioncity"]                     |
| bob   | ["newark","milpitas"]             |
| bob   | ["sanjose"]                       |
| bob   | ["santacruz"]                     |
```

Expected output

```
| key   | array_agg(distinct elem)   OR   array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(locations)))  |
| ----- | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| alice | [ miami, milpitas, redwoodshores, sancarlos, sanfrancisco, sanjose, sanmateo ] |
| bob   | [ freemont, milpitas, newark, onioncity, sanjose, santacruz ]                  |
```

Any pointers on how I can accomplish this with Singlestore ?

How I would do this in other DBs/Frameworks:

- Postgres - It was relatively simple to construct this query. I can create an array column and do `array_agg(distinct elem)` - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/58628/1
- Spark - as simple as `array_distinct( array_agg( col ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON_AGG function to achieve this.
This function does not support distinct like `json_agg(distinct(key_col))`, so using the distinct clause in CTE itself.

Docs: https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/reference/sql-reference/json-functions/json_agg.html

Sample Code

```
create table json_array_example (key_col text, locations json);


insert into json_array_example values('alice', '["sanjose", "sancarlos", "miami"]');
insert into json_array_example values('alice', '["sanjose","milpitas"]');
insert into json_array_example values('alice', '["miami"]');
insert into json_array_example values('alice', '["sanmateo","sanfrancisco"]');
insert into json_array_example values('alice', '["redwoodshores","sanfrancisco"]');
insert into json_array_example values('bob'  , '["sanjose","milpitas"]');
insert into json_array_example values('bob'  , '["freemont","onioncity"]');
insert into json_array_example values('bob'  , '["onioncity"]');
insert into json_array_example values('bob'  , '["newark","milpitas"]');
insert into json_array_example values('bob'  , '["sanjose"]');
insert into json_array_example values('bob'  , '["santacruz"]');


WITH t AS (SELECT distinct key_col, table_col AS locations
           FROM json_array_example
                    JOIN TABLE(JSON_TO_ARRAY(locations)))
select key_col, json_agg(locations) as locations
from t
group by key_col;
```